# Failed to apply plugin in android studio

Tags: plugins

I am working on an app its work good. after i apply external plugin that return error Failed to apply plugin .

my build tool version 2.2.3
and compile version 24

Unfortunately, the suggestion of G.K. did not work!

Answer (score 1):

Please run the following command in your terminal:

.gradlew clean --refresh-dependencies

This will grap the newest version of the Calldorado plugin that is causing this error. The newest version has a fix in it.